# phpmyadmin on lighttpd gives me a 403 forbidden need help

Tags: lighttpd, localhost, http-status-code-403

#### Whats the problem:

When I goto //localhost/phpmyadmin I get what I would get if I did //localhost/, I'm using both http: and https:.

#### What did I do, that changed it:

I simply reinstalled lighttpd.

#### What I have tried:

- Disabling and re-enabling 50-phpmyadmin.conf, Now I get a "403 - Forbidden" instead.
- When I goto /phpmyadmin/setup it asks me for a login, Not a clue what it is.
- Now I'm waiting for someone to help. :) Thanks to anyone with any answers.

  ---

### Latest Status:

Not working, giving me a "403 - Forbidden".

Comment: Humm, I deleted this unanswered question by mistake, but I got what I needed to re-post it.

Comment: Add to question 50-phpmyadmin.conf file.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that fastcgi and fastcgi-php modules are enabled in lighttpd:

```
lighty-enable-mod fastcgi
lighty-enable-mod fastcgi-php
```